# Стоит ли применять паттерн итератор

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, итераторы

Доброго времени суток.

Вопрос следующий: имеется двумерный массив объектов. Несколько модулей в программе регулярно запрашивают какую-то часть этого массива и последовательно перебирают её элементы. Для некоторых модулей порядок обхода не важен, но для некоторых это критично. Так например один модуль запрашивает "прямоугольный" кусок этого двумерного массива и ему нужно дважды пробежаться по каждой строке начиная с верхней. Так вот, уместно ли применять паттерн итератор в случае, если порядок обхода для его клиентов критически важен и каждому клиенту может понадобиться установить свой порядок обхода, при этом придется реализовывать несколько итераторов с разным интерфейсом? И если нет, подскажите пожалуйста, стоит ли тогда передовать клиентам непосредственно сам двумерный массив с учетом, что может понадобиться изменить способ хранения данных? Какое архитектурное решение лучше подойдет в данном случаи?

Comment: Почему разные интерфейсы должны быть именно у итераторов? Скорее должны быть разные классы, предоставляющие разные выборки. Да, они будут возвращать разные итераторы, но интерфейс у них будет один. Данные лучше оставить на месте, если их много (сотни и больше). Если десятки или меньше, возможно, стоит возвращать массивы ссылок на них.
Кстати, скажите, "дважды пробегаться" это как именно? потребитель должен получить массив строк и итерировать каждую строку дважды, или получить единую последовательность с задвоенными участками?

Comment: @Nikolay Под дважды пробегаться я хотел сказать - дважды итерировать каждую строку полученного массива. А что насчет различия интерфейсов итераторов - ведь чтобы пробежать строку дважды клиент должен знать когда строка закночится, а потом иметь возможность повторить эту строку, т.е. уже нужны методы hasItemInRow() и repeatRow(), когда другим клиентам достаточно hasNext(), next(). Некоторые клиентам может понадобиться пройти возвращенные данные целиком несколько раз подряд, пройти полученные данные не строками а столбцами и т.д.

Comment: При этом в интерфейсе итератора появляется очень много методов, где только небольшая часть будет использоваться всеми или несколькими клиентами. А также получается, что сами методы, их названия и назначение очень ясно говорят что за структуру данных я использую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Общие рекомендации**

Стоит сделать либо один класс с несколькими методами, предоставляющими выборки, либо несколько классов, по одному на вид выборки, и раздать их потребителям.

Каждый метод выборки должен возвращать специализированный итератор. Но интерфейсы у итераторов будут одинаковыми: это обычный Java-интерфейс `Iterator`.

**По поводу выборки прямоугольной области и двойных итераций по строкам:**

Стоит сделать так: метод выборки возвращает итератор по объектам типа `Row` (добавьте какой-либо свой префикс), реализующий интерфейс `Iterable`. Каждый такой объект имеет ссылку на строку данных и поля `first` и `length`, и из него можно получить итератор по такому "слайсу". Таким образом можно итерироваться и по строкам и по элементам:

```java
Iterable<RectRow> rows = someQuerier.getRect(left, top, width, height);
for (RectRow row : rows) {
    // многократный проход по одной и той же строке
    for (int rowPassCount = 0; rowPassCount < maxRowPassCount; rowPassCount += 1) {
        for (YourItem item : row) {
            // Ваши действия с элементом
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо @Nikolay Lebedev. Я правильно понял, что в случаи с выборкой прямоугольной области и двойной итерации по строкам нужно просто сделать итератор, метод next() которого просто возвращает ещё один итератор, который в свою очередь уже итерируется по строкам?

Comment: Почти. Итератор строк должен при вызове `Next` возвращать не `Iterator<Item>`, а `Iterable<Item>` - то есть строку "прямоугольного слайса". Потом оператор цикла `for` извлечет из нее итератор и обойдет ее.